# Nonparametric hypothesis testing to infer that the population variance belongs to a certain interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, references, inference, estimators

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be either or small or large. Let $\{x_1 \dots x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a random sample generated by a random vector $X \in \mathbb{R}.$ The test(s) I'm aiming for are about inferring whether the $var[X]= \sigma_X^2$ is less than or equal to a certain positive number, when we *know* the mean; but of course, if such a test exists, with an *unknown* mean would be even better!

I'm *not* assuming any distributional assumption (e.g. normality) in general (in fact if the samples are non-negative, I doubt whether we can assume that, since normal distributions takes both positive and negative values). I'd guess in this case one can have the sample mean or the population mean high enough so that the probability of taking negative values is very small; but assume, if you need a form of the distribution, if necessary to answer - including normality. **Hence I'd *prefer* a non-parametric test for variance with no distributional assumptions** - the *three cases I want to test* will follow shortly.

**Note:** In my case $X \ge 0$ is a nonnegative random vector, but I feel that shouldn't change the answers at the end. Below are the null hypotheses $H_0$ and the alternate hypotheses $H_1.$ Fix $\sigma_0, \sigma_1 > 0.$

**The cases are as follows:**

Case I: $H_0: \sigma_X^2 \le \sigma_0^2, H_1: \sigma_X^2 > \sigma_0^2.$

Case II:  $H_0: \sigma_X^2 < \sigma_0^2, H_1: \sigma_X^2 \ge \sigma_0^2.$ (I guess this is very similar to Case I but still just being careful and writing it separately.

Case III: $H_0: \sigma_X^2 \in (\sigma_0^2, \sigma_1^2), H_1: \sigma_X^2 \ge \sigma_0^2 $ or $\sigma_X^2 \ge \sigma_0^2$

I searched online for these tests but I mostly got *parametric tests* (e.g. in this [online book](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/hypothesis-testing-variance)) and [this online handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda358.htm), but all I'm getting is when the null hypothesis is $H_0: \sigma_X^2 = \sigma_0^2$ versus the alternate one: $H_1: \sigma_X^2 < \sigma_0^2, \sigma_X^2 > \sigma_0^2, \sigma_X^2 \ne  \sigma_0^2$.

Comment: You say in your title "parametric/non-parametric" but in your body text the only parametric assumption you mention is one you're not willing to make. Which parametric assumption do you want to look at instead?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your comment! I'm trying to understand your question better - did you mean that I'm not willing to assume normality and hence my only way would be through non-parametric testing? If yes, then I'm ok with normality I guess -  so I wrote "but assume what you want to answer". Sorry if I didn't udnerstand your question correctly. But modifying my question accordingly in a minute.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. Your title mentions *parametric [...] hypothesis testing*, implying you want (among other things) a test based on some parametric distributional model. There are infinitely many parametric models - of which you excluded one of them, but mention no others on which to base a parametric test. Your assumptions are your own; no obvious choices exist for anyone else to make/suggest since your description is completely abstract, not grounded in any specific variables. If you want a parametric assumption, by all means make one.

Comment: If you want to know about some commonly used tests you could ask about those (ones making specific parametric assumptions generally assume normality but there's no particular reason they need to do that rather than something else). However, there are already many questions on site that relate to those.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the clarification - I understand better now. So yes, I excluded the normality, but of course there could be other models (e.g. $\chi^2$), specially when the distribution is non-negative. But honestly, from my only course in hypothesis taken before 2005, I don't really know in general how to proceed with this problem in the first place - I'd definitely prefer the non-parametric approach, and I'm going to mention this bit of detail now.

Comment: I just saw your second comment - yes I could ask about the commonly used tests, but  I did a quick search online (not on this site yet), and I wasn't able to locate a non-parametric test for interval estimation of variance, may be I missed soemthign obvious. If you could just point me to a question that deals with non-parametric estimation of interval for population variance, that'd be very helpfyl.

Comment: The things you say you don't know about in your two comments are things you could ask for (there may be things that can be done in some of the cases in your question)

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica OK thanks, I'll look up the permutation test and bootstrap test - maybe these are the answers to my question! I edited the question, and I'm aware that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator of population variance, but what I'm aiming for here is: without any distributional assumption, how good is that estimate to inform me that the population var is less than a threshold, given the sample?

Comment: Those things are general approaches to nonparametric tests which I removed from my comment since - if they work for any parts of your specific question here, which they might not -  belong in an answer, where details might be given

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Okay thanks - I'll look them up anyway, and you're welcome to write an answer.